# Does a green's function of a Laplacian, in one dimensions, with periodic boundary conditions, exist?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, greens-function

solve $$y'' = \delta(x-0.25)$$ $$y(0) = y(1), y'(0) = y'(1)$$ Does this have a solution? I couldn't construct one with this boundary conditions and would like to see a solution if it exists.

Answer (score 1):

You can ask for a solution of the boundary problem or for a Green kernel for the operator $L[y]=y''$, but not both.

As the question for the Green kernel is the more general one, consider the more general equation for it, that is, for $y(x)=G(a,x)$ consider
$$
y''=δ(x−a)
$$
for any fixed $a\in(0,1)$. This implies a jump of $1$ in $y'$ at $x=a$, while outside that point the derivative is constant. This means that you can not have the same derivative at both interval ends, as $y'(1)=1+y'(0)$.

Answer (score 0):

$$y(x) = ax+b+c(x-t)H(x-t)$$

$$y' = a+cH(x-t)$$

$$y'' = c\delta(x-t)$$

$$y(0) = b$$
$$y(1) = a + b + c$$
$$y'(0) = a$$
$$y'(1) = a+c$$

$$a+c = 0$$
$c = 0$
$a = 0$

Hence such a periodic green's function of the Laplacian not possible.